# Dynamic bean selection

Tags: spring, javabeans

I have a service I write with Spring Boot. There are three beans in the service. I can statically run the bean that I want in the test phase with the qualifier annotation, but I want the user to be able to dynamically select the bean that he wants. How do I run the selected Bean?

Comment: `if (choice.equals("bean 1") { bean1.run(); }`? You really need to clarify your question. And to post the relevant code.

Comment: Probably this: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/combining-strategy-pattern-and-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a common interface for all the three beans and have this interface in your service with @autowired. From your test program you can inject whatever bean you want in to this service.